# Software Engineering - clarity of purpose

Tags: support, stack-overflow, scope

I currently have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691531/measuring-program-programming-mathematical-elegance) on Stack Overflow trying to find out sources for work on the metrication of various aspects of software such as usability and functionality (I labelled them, for convenience in questioning, software elegance).

The proposed remit and name of Software Engineering having changed, I am having some difficulties following the subtleties of the differences between the proposed and original remit.

To be concrete, and to aid my understanding of the proposed new direction and naming of the software engineering site, would a question of the type I describe above fit in with Stack Overflow (it does feel as if it does not fit there exactly); the original remit of the Software Engineering site (it did feel from the site51 material, that this was an appropriate home); the proposed new remit (this is where I start to feel very unsure about the goodness of fit); or the Programmers.Stackexchange.com (which until the change in remit, I had not come across, or investigated).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having trouble parsing your use of the words, "metrication" and "remit."  Could you explain what you mean by your use of these words?

Comment: w​​​​​​​​​​​hat

Comment: I believe the answer is "7".

Comment: @Robert I believe he's trying to figure out what's the difference between the original Software Engineering proposal and the new Software Engineering proposal besides the name.

Comment: @Mark - yes I am trying to figure out the difference between the two (and what is the appropriate home for my question).

@Robert - I was using remit to cover the description and meaning of the description, for the original and revised proposal for that site. For metrication see my comment on @JonSeigel's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with it staying on Stack Overflow.

We have discussions about coding style there (although I suppose that topic has been mostly exhausted), and this is taking it a step further to attempt to measure coding style (assuming I've understood correctly).

The only thing I would consider doing is editing the post to rephrase the title in the form of a question, so it's more obvious what you're seeking.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will feed in edits to further clarify what I am after.  I am indeed trying to take things a step further to measure coding style. I am trying to find work being done, not just on measuring coding style, but also on measuring functionality and usability.

Comment: I will continue with Stack Overflow. I will also start supporting the IEEE/ACM Software Engineering proposal, which is the revised one.

Comment: @Chris: Okay, great. I think your question is interesting. Best of luck finding an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are quite right.  The kind of language you use drives a true software engineer [like Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2005/10/21.html) pretty batty.  SO is not a good home for that.  Avoid looking for Area 51 proposals that have "engineer" in the title, you need to aim for "architect".  I think I saw one.  Even in meta you might want to avoid phrases like "feed in edits" btw.  It's a bit, erm, uncouth.  Good luck.

Comment: The Software Architect proposal has been closed in Area 51 as it overlaps the IEEE/ACM Software Engineering proposal.